# what is difference between testing functionality in browser and same in mobile

Tags: selenium, webdriver, mobile-application

I today had basic question in my mind ,what is the difference between
testing  functionality in browser and same in mobile. say testing
m.gmail.com in browser and same directly in mobile using selenium.Is
there any difference other than the fitting into screen etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have a different server to handle mobile requests, you might have different implementation of the features, thus, you need to test both platforms.

The content might also be delivered according to the mobile browser used (Safari on the iPhone is much more feature-rich than the default N95 browser, for example).

Answer (score 0):

**Let’s look at some of the major differences.**

1. Limited Real Estate
   The most obvious difference is screen size. Responsive design is relatively easy to code for desktop and laptop browsers – most of which come with predefined ratios anyway.

By contrast, mobile devices are much smaller. Aligning images and text becomes a real challenge – especially when you factor in features like portrait orientation (i.e. the ability to rotate a mobile device and have the image flip accordingly).

Worse still, there is so much more variation – even when dealing with the same manufacturer.

For example, the iPhone 5 has a 4” display, whereas the iPhone 6 is 4.7” on the diagonal. When you add in the iPhone 6 Plus (5.5”), iPad Mini (7.9”), and iPad standard (9.7”), it becomes harder and harder to code and test mobile applications that look “good” on all screens.

2. Storage and RAM
   Screens are not the only spatial constraint mobile software testers face. You also must factor in the limited storage and processing power of today’s mobile devices. Even high capacity phones can quickly fill up as users download apps and multimedia.

In the browser world, such constraints are moot. Desktop storage is essentially unlimited (measured in terabytes). And cloud-based storage is easy to increase, even if this requires charging higher prices to end-users.

3. Internet Access
   With the exception of a few off-line browser applications (e.g. Gmail), Web-based software always requires an Internet connection.

Mobile apps may or may not need online access (although those that don’t often take up more space – see point #2 above). When Internet is needed, however, mobile software testers must factor in 3G and 4G – in addition to normal Wi-Fi.